# What does a struct inside a struct imply in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

The following code is supposed to create a singly linked list in C. I wish to understand what insert_node does with pointer head. What does "head" points to each time insert_node is called?

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next; 
};
typedef struct node node;

    node* head = NULL; 

void insert_node(int data) {
    node *new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node)); 
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = head;
    head = new_node;
}
```

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question title as it is a little misleading.

Comment: The first line allocates memory for a 'struct node' for creating the new node. The second line fills up the data field in this newly created node. The third line sets up the next pointer to the existing head, thereby linking this node to the existing linked list. The fourth line marks this new node as the new head.

Comment: Thank you, and I think I can read the third and fourth lines to be, "the pointer address of `new_node->next` is changed to the pointer address of `head`, which points to a NULL value, and then the pointer address of `head` is changed to the pointer address of `new_node`, which is a struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`head` will point to the beginning of the linked list (the first entry in the list). To get subsequent elements you just follow the `next` pointer inside the `node`.

Every time you add a new node, you set the `next` of the new element to the current `head` and set `head` to the new element so you chain the elements together.

Comment: Isn't "new_node->next = head;" makes the next node the "head"? Then "head" points to the new node? I am utterly confused.

Comment: `new_node->next = head` sets the current `head` as the 2nd element of the list. `head = new_node` sets the new node as the beginning of the list.

Comment: After `head = new_node`, what is `new_node->next`?

Comment: @Pippi The value of `new_node->next` is the old value of `head`. Changing `head` after the assignment doesn't change `new_node->next`

Answer (score 2):

Q: What does a struct inside a struct imply in C?

A: In this case, "struct node *" is just used as a pointer, to a list item of type "struct node".

This is a type declaration:

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next; 
};
```

This is a variable definition: `node* head = NULL;`  It's equivalent to saying `struct node * head = NULL;`

And this is a variable assignment: `node *new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));`

The variable "head" is just a pointer to the start of your list.  It's your "starting point" any time you want to use the list: including adding stuff, or finding stuff in the list.

"Next" always points to the "next item in the list".  "Head" is null before you initialize the list.  Each "next" is always null when it's the last item in the list.

"Head" only changes once - when you initialize the list.  "Next" changes twice: 1) it's set to null when the node is first added, and 2) it's reset to point to the next node, when a subsequent node is added.

'Hope that helps ..